# Prove that the set of $2\times 2$ matrices with integer entries whose determinant is equal to $1$ is a group under multiplication

Tags: group-theory

Prove that the set of $2 \times 2$ matrices with integer entries whose determinant is equal to $1$ is a group under multiplication.

My question doesn't pertain to how to do this but more to a roadblock I am having when I interpret the conditions.  Specifically it applies to finding the identity and the inverse. I know that the ordinary identity matrix is the identity of the group,  but the procedure to find it has me a little perplexed.

Question: Since we are dealing with "integers" this would mean I cannot "divide out" my values to obtain the identity matrix because that would involve me using rational numbers. So what would I do to find the identity?

Comment: Why would you need to "divide out" by value to get the identity matrix?  How would solve this problem for the rational matrices with determinant $1$?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding but because the determinant is 1 then the elements of any inverse matrix will still be integers and hence no fractions required.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I would use the gaussian row reduction procedure with the identity matrix attached to the other side

Comment: What do you mean find it? You don't need to find it, because it is there. It is a matrix with 1's on the diagonal and thus all entries are integers. Do you mean proving it is the identity? That would just be by definition.

Comment: @Prospect, I know which matrix it is, but for the sake of argument (amd what I am trying to figure out) say I did not know it was the usual identity matrix. I would have to follow the definition of what the identity is supposed to do to a group element amd then find it.  I am asking how to go about that

Comment: Use Cramer's rule to prove that the inverse matrices will have integer coefficients.

Comment: Then realize that matrices come from linear transformations. Take the identity homomorphism on a $2$-dimensional space and fix a basis, then you can easily write down the identity matrix from there.

Comment: Instead of row-reduction, use the cofactor formula for the determinant

Comment: @dc3rd many groups can naturally be thought of as actions on a set. For example, matrices can naturally be thought of as linear transformations. In any such group, the group element that does not change the set acted upon will be the identity.

Comment: How does the cofactor formula help in finding he identity?  I understand to find the determinant,  but the identity?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the cofactor formula for the **inverse**

Comment: When you speak of the cofactor formula for the inverse, you mean $\frac{1}{detA}(adjA) $ ? Isn't that still division?

Comment: The inverse matrix is $\frac {1}{det A} \times adjugate$ as the determinant is 1 then the inverse will only consist of integer components.

Comment: I agree that $det(A) = 1$ and it will go away,  but is that not technically still division? Just because it so happened to disappear doesn't take away from that.  I'm sure there is some scenario where the $det(A)\neq 1$

Comment: I understand what you are saying but isn't the determinant 1 a given property of the matrices by assumption and not one you are computing?

Comment: Yes it is a given property.......but that doesn't impact the "procedure"...I think....

Comment: @dc3rd you're allowed to divide integers by $1$

Comment: Is that a general rule @Omnomnomnom?  or specific to this  question?  I apologize for my pedantry, I am just trying to solidify my understanding

Comment: It's a general rule: both $1$ and $-1$ have multiplicative inverses in the integers.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is associative. The product of two matrices with determinant $1$ again has determinant $1$.

Also, the inverse matrix of a matrix with determinant $1$ has determinant $1$, and there is a neutral elelement, namely $I$ with determinant $1$.

It remains to show that the inverse of an integer matrix with determinant $1$ is again an integer matrix. This can be easily done using the formula with adjoints and the determinant of a matrix : The adjoints are, of course, integers and the denominator (the determinant of the matrix) is $1$.

Putting altogether, this proves the claim.

Answer (score 0):

The group is $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and it is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, which has the identity matrix $I_2$ as neutral element. Since $I_2$ has integer coefficients, we conclude that $I_2$ is the neutral element of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ as well. Because we have $\det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det(A)}$ we conclude that $\det(A)$ must be a divisor of $1$, i.e., $\det(A)=\pm 1$ for all $A\in GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.